# Using posix_spawn() with setuid() & setgid()

Tags: fork, posix, glibc, spawn, execv

There appears to be a bug in my version of glibc 2.13 that make repeated calls to fork()/execv() dangerous, resulting in crash and memory corruption. This seems to occur roughly 1-2% of the time. The current code flow is as follow

1. parent forks child process
2. child closes all inherited file descriptors except for stdin, stdout, stderr
3. child runs setgid and setuid to not be running as root any longer
4. Execv binary which should be run

If I replace the above 4 steps with just the use of posix_spawn(), my program never crashes. This seems to validate my hypothesis that my current glibc has a bug in it with fork/execv.

The issue with replacing steps 1-4 with posix_spawn() is that it provides no mechanism for me to accomplish steps 2 & 3, which are extremely important for resource management and security. Is there any alternative solution or something i have not considered in order to get a stable version working?

Answer (score 0):

> If I replace the above 4 steps with just the use of posix_spawn(), my program never crashes. This seems to validate my hypothesis that my current glibc has a bug in it with fork/execv.

glibc 2.13 uses `fork` and `execve` in the implementation of `posix_spawn`. It is probably a different bug in your code. Only in glibc 2.24 and later, `posix_spawn` avoids using `fork` by default (which implies not running `fork` handlers at all, and those can be a source of crashes or hangs).

> The issue with replacing steps 1-4 with posix_spawn() is that it provides no mechanism for me to accomplish steps 2 & 3, which are extremely important for resource management and security. Is there any alternative solution

The only way to do this is to introduce a wrapper program which closes all file descriptors, switches IDs, and then launches the actual target program.